# Javascript: How to go to parent directory in javascript?

Tags: javascript

path variable prints `localhost:8080//webapps/test/htmlFiles`

Then I'm using

```
var filePath=${path}../test.html
```

But it's taking like this-

```
http://localhost:8080/webapps/test/htmlFiles/../test.html
```

I need like this

```
http://localhost:8080/webapps/test/test.html
```

Comment: Those two points to same destination. If you want the exact string, then you need to use regex.

Comment: Those URLs should be treated equivalently.